# Failed to build Diff-0.4.0 (why?)

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

```
   |
18 | import Data.Monoid (mappend)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
cabal: Failed to build Diff-0.4.0 (which is required by
test:cardano-cli-golden from cardano-cli-1.33.0).
```

Comment: What versions of ghc and cabal are you using? Have you run `cabal update` ? How much RAM does your machine have?

Comment: I am facing the same problem and am stuck. [nix-shell:~/cardano-src/cardano-node]$ cat /home/wims/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/dependent-sum-0.7.1.0-a9b93f488664d838e88fc29667167f9b0174f527c76ea1751582c678600794a8.log
Configuring library for dependent-sum-0.7.1.0..
Preprocessing library for dependent-sum-0.7.1.0..
Building library for dependent-sum-0.7.1.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Data.Dependent.Sum ( src/Data/Dependent/Sum.hs, dist/build/Data/Dependent/Sum.o, dist/build/Data/Dependent/Sum.dyn_o )
/nix/store/f0rrfmf8kh5bsiql5bbq7m4h3xgihpnx-binutils-2.38/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: e

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4080)

Answer (score 0):

Found the same issue when executing :
cabal build cardano-node cardano-cli

following steps in https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/

I'm using Ubuntu on Virtual box with 2GB RAM